# How to set the LaTeX font size in inkscape?

Tags: latex, inkscape

In inkscape using Extensions->Render->LaTeX formula you can enter LaTeX into your Inkscape image.  The default font is huge however. How can you change it to something smaller?

Alternatively, is there a better way to enter LaTeX in an inkscape image that is easy to install in quantal?

Comment: just for clarification, you refer to a "better way to enter LaTeX" in an Inkscape image, right?

Comment: @carnendil Yes that is right.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add a latex specification for the font size.
For example, you can use `\fontsize` in the "latex formula" box:

```tex
\fontsize{9pt}{1em} $\sum_{ij} w_{ij}$
```

Comment: This is extremely useful when you try to make a figure with several different font sizes!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I haven't used it yet, but the extension [textext](http://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/) allows you to set an **scale factor** which:

> (...) affects how much a newly created LaTeX object is magnified. You can later change/reset this via `Object` -> `Transform` -> `Matrix`.

Comment: what's the difference between the textext and the Extensions->Render->Latex ? (I do not have the later in my inkscape and I still haven't found out how to have it )